# JQuery custom function called in html?

Tags: jquery, function, firefox

I´m using an old version of Firefox (I can´t update it because of various reasons). And I can´t use jQuery event handlers (they seem to leak memory on old browsers).

So I am forced to use the following code:

```
<div class="somediv" onclick="dostuff()"></div>
```

Problem is, the code won´t work. Why?

My Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   function dostuff()
   {
       $('#someotherdiv').html('hello');
   }
});
```

Comment: @Nicholas Butler - Hey Nicholas i appreciate you guys spell-correct me. But why remove my "Thanks in advance"? Is there something wrong with being polite? :-)

Comment: I like polite! But adding TIA and suchlike in questions is against site etiquette as it just adds clutter: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have placed the function inside the `ready` event handler, so it's local to that scope. Put the function in the root level so that it's available globally:

```
function dostuff() {
  $('#someotherdiv').html('hello');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // whatever you need to do when the page has loaded
});
```

Comment: Yes but then the function can be fired BEFORE DOM is ready. It does more stuff then the 'hello' message.

Comment: @Juw: When you declare the function globally, it exists from the start (below the script tag where it is declared). If the function does something with elements that might not exist yet (i.e. elements loaded later than the element that calls the function), you have to handle that inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

just put the function outside `$(document).ready(`, just as below there is no need to put function in `$(document).ready(`

```
function dostuff()
   {
       $('#someotherdiv').html('hello');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

your function goes here

```
 function dostuff()
   {
       $('#someotherdiv').html('hello');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way: Use jQuerys event system to assign a click handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.somediv').click(function () {
        $('#someotherdiv').html('hello');
    }
});
```

Comment: As i said in my original post. I can´t use the JQuery events because it seems to leak memory on old browsers